# Is it possible to get recently played games of user using a PlayStation Network API?

Tags: playstation

When playing on PlayStation, you get notifications when you're friends just played a game and whether they won or lost that game. Is it possible to get this information stream using a PlayStation Network API?

I found some unofficial PlayStation Network API's, but none seem to offer this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any API, but my first idea would be to use some sort of web scraping/crawling to accomplish this. And if you're lucky they might be utilizing HATEOAS and that would expand your options of where to branch your crawl/improve performance etc.

It would kind of be a niche API to create but it could be worth it.